# XSSFWorkbook mockito junit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for the below code where I am reading a file cloud bucket. But the `XSSFWorkbook` always gets empty file content.

```
try (ReadChannel excelReader = storage.reader(sourceId);
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(excelReader);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream))
```

Can anyone help me with how I can get data in my workbook?

Below is the code I have tried so far

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
final Storage mockStorage = mock(Storage.class);
final Blob blob = mock(Blob.class);
ReadChannel excelReader = mock(ReadChannel.class);
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(excelReader);
InputStream anyInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("mapping.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(anyInputStream);
MockedStatic<Channels> channels = mockStatic(Channels.class);
final MockedStatic<StorageOptions> storageOptionsMock =
Mockito.mockStatic(StorageOptions.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

storageOptionsMock
.when(() -> StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("Test").build().getService())
.thenReturn(mockStorage);

when(mockStorage.get(any(BlobId.class))).thenReturn(blob);
when(blob.getBucket()).thenReturn("test-bucket");
when(blob.getName()).thenReturn("sample.xls");
when(blob.getSize()).thenReturn(SIZE);
when(blob.getCacheControl()).thenReturn(CACHE_CONTROL);
when(blob.getComponentCount()).thenReturn(COMPONENT_COUNT);
when(blob.getContentEncoding()).thenReturn(CONTENT_ENCODING);
when(blob.getContentLanguage()).thenReturn(CONTENT_LANGUAGE);
when(blob.getContentType()).thenReturn(CONTENT_TYPE);
when(blob.getCrc32c()).thenReturn(CRC32C);
when(mockStorage.reader(any(BlobId.class))).thenReturn(excelReader);
channels.when(Channels.newInputStream(excelReader)).thenReturn(anyInputStream);
```